# How to make python re.sub won't miss pattern

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code:

```
re.sub(r"([GAT])G", r"\g<1>A", "GCGGG")
```

which gives me result: 'GCGAG',

But I really want to get is 'GCGAA', what should I do?

why is the last 'G' doesn't change to 'A'?

Comment: Matches can't overlap. There's no good way to make sense of the overlapping replacements. [Other regex libraries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) support overlapping matches, but still not for replacements.

Answer (score 0):

`GG` was the first match; its second `G` can’t participate in another match. You can use a [lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to check if a pattern is preceded by another pattern without including that check in the match, though:

```
re.sub(r"(?<=[GAT])G", "A", "GCGGG")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!